# view equivalent to dba_credentials in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a Database check for all versions of oracle(11g,12c,19c) to check the credentials set on a user using dba_credentials.(something like a metric extension)
But dba_credentials  is only available in Oracle 12c.
Is there any view in 11g i can use for this purpose using a 'case' in sql depending on the version?

Answer (score 1):

Credentials as a separate type of object didn't exist in 11g.  You set credentials as part of the `dbms_scheduler` package.  If you want to view those credentials, you can query the [`dba_scheduler_credentials` data dictionary table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2032.htm#REFRN20580).  Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, you may need to query that table in later versions as well since not everyone migrating to 12c will have switched over to the new way of managing credentials.